# My other forms do not get submitted

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

So I have created a page to print out a div for every chat in the database and each chat has a form attched to it. When I click on the form, the form gets submitted with the displayed none input and it's value sent to php to do other things. Now the problem is that only the first div's form gets submitted even though the code is the same.The form is right on the div and it is displayed absolute. The two forms are the same but I need both to work and to get to the same php code. Code: HTML

```
<div class="chaty">
<form method="post" action="index.php" name="chat_lox" id="chat_loc">
<input type="text" name="chat_locy" 
value="5e2dbe2be3b5927c588509edb1c46f7d">
</form>
<div class="chatDesc" id="84281145">
<div class="tit">Creator: </div>
<div class="iriss"><i id="close_chatn" onclick="closeChat(84281145)" 
class="material-icons">close</i></div>

<form action="mypage.php" method="post">


<div class="authr_name"><button value="John Brown" name="userlink" 
class="subm_as_text">Hitsuji</button></div>
</form>
<div class="titd"><h3>Description</h3></div>
<div class="description_chat">jaames</div>
</div>


<span onclick="openChat(84281145)">☰</span>
<div class="chatname"><h3>james</h3></div>
<div class="chatback"></div>
<div class="underlie"><p>Users: 1</p><p> Created: 2017/07/28 07:09:40pm</p>
</div>

</div>
<!-- one that doesn't work -->
<div class="chaty">
<form method="post" action="index.php" name="chat_lox" id="chat_loc">
<input type="text" name="chat_locy" 
value="9503e253936e716f18d9c57b4f97d618">
</form>
<div class="chatDesc" id="6179276">
<div class="tit">Creator: </div>
<div class="iriss"><i id="close_chatn" onclick="closeChat(6179276)" 
class="material-icons">close</i></div>

<form action="mypage.php" method="post">


<div class="authr_name"><button value="Hitsuji" name="userlink" 
class="subm_as_text">Hitsuji</button></div>
</form>
<div class="titd"><h3>Description</h3></div>
<div class="description_chat">The Army of JOhn</div>
</div>


<span onclick="openChat(6179276)">☰</span>
<div class="chatname"><h3>John Army</h3></div>
<div class="chatback"></div>
<div class="underlie"><p>Users: 2</p><p> Created: 2017/07/23 11:31:06am</p>
</div>

</div>
```

JS

```
$("#chat_loc").on("click",function() {
$(this).submit();
alert("submitted");

});
```

PHP

```
if(isset($_POST['chat_locy']) ? $_POST['chat_locy'] : null){echo "it 
worked";}
```

Comment: Only one form will submit at a time.

Comment: `id` __MUST BE UNIQUE__

Comment: Also, no need for a ternary operator as the condition, a single `isset()` is needed

Comment: you can't use same id on html tag option, id must be unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only submit only one form at a time. Try changing the id to a class such that all forms have same class like `'chat_loc'`.

For example, change the JavaScript to this:

```
$(".chat_loc").on("submit", function() {
   $(this).submit();
   alert("submitted");
});
```